# Notification Center / Embarcadero.DesktopToasts

Tags: delphi

When I call up the Notification Center, I get the value **Embarcadero.DesktopToasts.*????????*** as the reporting app for a limited period of time.

[image: Embarcadero.DesktopToasts]

If I delete the link created by Delphi in the `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs` directory and also the registry entries `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Notifications\Settings\Embarcadero.DesktopToasts.????????`
the app name will be correct again after the second call at the latest.

How can this behavior be corrected?

*As a side question, in which value can I store a better icon?*

Comment: Have you looked at https://www.tenforums.com/general-support/80933-notification-settings-what-embarcadero-desktop-toasts-cf4addbe.html?

Comment: @MartynA This page also describes my problem. It has no solution.

Comment: @MartynA That link gives me `Error 1020 Ray ID: 68c0f265afb51786 • 2021-09-09 14:01:08 UTC
Access denied
What happened?
This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks.` Seems like the website is protecting itself from being viewed, too. ;-)

Comment: @UliGerhardt I have encountered many people not being aware that their access to websites is re-routed thru 3rd party networks (i.e. VPNs, proxies, anti virus services...) instead of directly accessing it thru their ISP - and you could be one of them. [Cloudflare error 1020 = firewall block, contact site owner](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-1020-access-denied/66439)

Comment: I *am* going through a VPN - I think this is our corporate policy.

Answer (score 0):

For this to work, there needs to be alignment between the registry and a special shortcut to the application.

These shortcuts may be found by running "Shell:Appsfolder".

So, if a shortcut with a similar name as your program already exists, Embarcadero does not create a proper shortcut and notifications show up as Embarcadero.DesktopToasts....

Cleaning up the shortcuts with a similar name as your product may solve your problem.

(Perhaps Embarcadero should not have checked for shortname name, but for the actual content of this shortcut..)